# Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/impl/LongString" while retrieving messages from reply Q

Tags: spring-amqp

I am using spring-integration-amqp 4.1.4 with rabbitmq amqp-client 3.5.3. Messages are being delivered alright but reply messages retrieval raises following exception.

`org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer` - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/impl/LongString
```

[exception logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2bH7G3wTv26QzUzMVdkcmJLZDQ&authuser=0)

Comment: Please consider formatting your question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider formatting your question correctly.

It seems that you have a dependency that depends itself on an old version  of rabbitmq-java-client (<2.6). `LongString` package is now [`com.rabbitmq.client`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.5.3/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.5.3/index.html?com/rabbitmq/client/LongString.html) not [`com.rabbitmq.client.impl`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v2.5.1/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-2.5.1/index.html?com/rabbitmq/client/impl/LongString.html)

If you are using maven, try to launch a `mvn dependency:tree > deps.txt`, open `deps.txt` and find which dependency cause this issue.

You could try to depend directly on `amqp-client`, but it may hide the issue:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
  <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```